# Check file's whole raw text content exists as part of another file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep, diff

big1.txt:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

big2.txt:

```
f
c
g
h
i
b
```

small.txt:

```
b
c
```

Within a bash script, how can I tell that the whole ordered content of small.txt exists in another file?

Example:

`??? small.txt big1.txt` should return `true`

`??? small.txt big2.txt` should return `false`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: [linux determine if file1 is part of file2](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+determine+if+file1+is+part+of+file2). The first hit is `grep -vf file2 file1`. The second hit is `grep -q` in a for loop. The third hit is [How to check whether file1 is a prefix of file2?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/135016/56041) from [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), and uses [`cmp -s`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cmp).

Comment: Actually I removed my first post it has not been well received. I have been asked to provide a minimal exemple to test the thing. So that's it. And now I have to show the efforts I have already made? No I prefer to stick to a stricly minimal question and a minimal exemple. Actually I am making the question I was hoping to find first. Also I am not here to receive a mark on my work.
On the other hand, I felt my problem should be very simple to an experienced user, but I'm starting to think it may not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If big1.txt and big2.txt not too big (can be loaded in memory). Following test may be sufficient.

```
# to store file content into variables
big1=$(< big1.txt)
big2=$(< big2.txt)
small=$(< small.txt)

# to run from test case
big1=$'a\nb\nc\nd\ne\n'
big2=$'f\nc\ng\nh\ni\nb\n'
small=$'b\nc\n'

if [[ ${big1} = *${small}* ]]; then echo "big1"; fi
if [[ ${big2} = *${small}* ]]; then echo "big2"; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the way to discover that two complicated things are 'equal' is to do some cheap test that is true if they are equal and rarely true if they are not.  Those that pass this hueristic test are then checked more carefully ... but only rarely so full equality test can be expensive and yet not be triggered on every compare.

What I would do in this circumstance is take all the files, and sort their lines. (You might want to suppress blank lines if you are looking for matching text, and strip lines with trailing blanks, but that's your choice).   Probably useful to delete duplicate lines.

Now compare each file, to all longer files to see if it is a prefix.  (Can't be a prefix if the other file is shorter, thus we get rid of 1/2 the compares just based on sizes).  If sorted file A is a prefix of sorted file B, then you can run a more complicated test to see if the real file A is embeded in file B (which I suspect will be true with high probability if the sorted files pass the prefix test).

Having had this idea, we can now optimize it.  Instead of storing lines of text, we take each file, and hash each line, giving a file of hash codes.  Sort these.  Follow the rest of the procedure.

Next trick: decide our hash codes are 8 bits or 16 bits in size.  This makes them fit into a character of your favorite programming language.  Now your prefix-compare test can consist of collecting the character-sized hash codes per file, and doing a string compare of shorter ones against longer ones.  At this point we've moved the problem from reading the disk to comparing efficiently in memory; we probably can't speed it up much because disk reads are very expensive compared to in memory computations.

Comment: Thank you, that is very interesting. Regarding my problem, performance is not really an issue but I'm starting to suspect those approches of being easier to implement with the existing commands.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ diff small big1.txt | grep -q '^<'
$ echo $?
1

$ diff small big2.txt | grep -q '^<'
$ echo $?
0

$ ! (diff small big1.txt | grep -q '^<')
$ echo $?
0

$ ! (diff small big2.txt | grep -q '^<')
$ echo $?
1

$ if diff small big1.txt | grep -q '^<'; then echo "does not exit"; else echo "does exist"; fi
does exist

$ if diff small big2.txt | grep -q '^<'; then echo "does not exit"; else echo "does exist"; fi
does not exit
```

Comment: This is the best answer technically speaking but needs explanation for those uninitiated.

Comment: Or those uninitiated could just try the different parts of it separately, and/or read the man pages and either way learn much more than if they were spoon fed the trivial details of this specific answer.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, where we spoil the newbies ;)

Answer (score 0):

check this please

```
if perl -0777 -e '$n = <>; $h = <>; exit(index($h,$n)<0)' small.txt big.txt
then echo small.txt is found in big.txt
fi
```